# Can't compile OpenGL project under OSX

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, osx-yosemite, glew

There's an OpenGL project I have to work on for a course I am attending.
There were link errors due to GLEW. After some research, I found out that on OSX GLEW is not necessary.

I included following headers.

```
//#include "CL/cl_gl.h"
#include <OpenGL/glu.h>
#include <OpenGL/gl.h>
//#include <OpenGL/glext.h> 
//#include <GLUT/glut.h>
```

But I am still getting compile errors of following kind:

```
  use of undeclared identifier 'GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER_EXT'
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER_EXT, 0);
                  ^
```

Where on OSX is the GLenum GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER_EXT resp. GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The EXT variant will only be defined in `glext.h` or the headers which come or are generated by the various GL extenstion loaders. The actual `GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER` enum is defined in `OpenGL/gl3.h`. On OSX, modern GL is part of the OS, and you can directly link the modern GL funtions. However, I would still recommend using some GL loader, just for portability reasons.

Comment: Actually it is a multi-platform project, it uses GLEW and GLFW as wrappers, I think these are the loaders you were referring to. But I could not get GLEW to link. Since I only have to write some shaders, I didn't want to bother too much.